# Current flow in a specific scenario

Tags: circuit-analysis, parallel

I'm pretty new to electronics and came across a fact I don't quite understand. If you have the below circuit, there are 2 situations:

1. The switch is not pressed: Lamp 1,2,3 and 4 will glow.
2. The switch is pressed: Only Lamp 1 and 2 glow.

I can't understand why in the second scenario only lamp 1 and 2 are glowing.
It seems like the current choses the "shortest path", but why won't it then in scenario 1 ignore lamp 4 and just flow through lamp3?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f4q1Yt.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Hi Bobface, here is a [great link](https://www.ibiblio.org/kuphaldt/electricCircuits/DC/DC_5.html) to study.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason lamps 3 and 4 don't light when the switch is closed is because there is no voltage across them.  Another way to look at it is that the switch becomes a 0 Ω resistor.  Parallel resistances share current inversely proportional to their resistance.  Since the inverse of 0 Ω is infinitely more than the inverse of 100 Ω, the switch takes all the current.

With the switch open, it is essentially not there.  Your mistake there is to take placement in a schematic as meaning something, and forgetting that lines are short circuits.  The path thru lamp 3 is not shorter somehow than the one thru lamp 4.  Physical placement doesn't matter, and can't be inferred from the schematic anyway.

This confusion is brought about by the common, but wrong, "rule" that current follows the shortest path.  It doesn't.  It follows paths of lower resistance more strongly.  It doesn't follow just one path (assuming the paths have neither infinite or 0 resistance), but splits according to the inverse of the resistance thru each path.

For example, consider a 3 Ω and 5 Ω resistor are in parallel.  This means they each present a alternate path to current.  The 3 Ω resistor will get 5/8 of the current, and the 5 Ω resistor the other 3/8 of the current.  The current is shared proportionally.  It's not all or nothing.  In your case, lamp 3 and lamp 4 have the same resistance, so they will share the current equally.

Since all the numbers are given, it is possible to tell exactly what this current will be.  First, we need to determine the overall current.  That is V1 divided by the total resistance connected to it.  Since lamp 3 and 4 are two 100 Ω resistors in parallel, they look like one 50 Ω resistor together.  This 50 Ω equivalent resistance is in series with the 100 Ω from each of lamps 1 and 2, for a total of 250 Ω.  (1 V)/(250 Ω) = 4 mA, which is the current that V1 will produce.  Since lamps 3 and 4 share this current equally, there will be 2 mA flowing thru each of them.

Just for fun, let's see what goes on in the switch closed case.  Now you only have lamps 1 and 2 in series with nothing else (SW1 has become just another connection and could be replaced by a solid line in the schematic).  The series combination of lamp 1 and 2 is 200 Ω.  (1 V)/(200 Ω) = 5 mA, which is what will flow thru each of lamp 1 and lamp 2.

Answer (score 6):

Current doesn't choose the shortest path - it chooses all paths in (inverse) proportion to the resistance of those paths.

The resistance of all the lamps is shown - the resistance of the wires is not, but it's conventional (wrong but close enough) to assume it is zero.

So with a choice of 2 100 ohm lamps the current divides equally between each. With the same choice plus a zero ohm alternative, virtually all will take the short circuit, and not much ( 0 / 100, i.e. none) will choose the path of either lamp.

(Beyond this brief overview, see Olin's excellent answer, and Ohm's Law.)

Comment: Very good point. It should read exactly this in textbooks instead of "shortest path."

Comment: @rdtsc Any 'text book' which has anything about current taking the 'shortest path' should be burnt ...

Answer (score 1):

For current to flow in the circuit there has to be a voltage "pushing" the current through. When you close SW1 you effectively short circuit lamps 3 and 4 - there is no voltage across them, so no current can flow.

BTW when you close SW1 lamps 1 and 2 will now glow brighter.